# PeekNamedPipe fails, but GetLastError returns 0

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe, getlasterror

I'm confused by the Windows API. I try to see if there are bytes left in an anonymous pipe using `PeekNamedPipe`. This function fails, but `GetLastError()` does not return an error.

The relevant part of my code is

```
if( !PeekNamedPipe( handle, NULL, 0, NULL, &numBytesAvailable, NULL ) )
  throw PeekNamedPipeException( "GetLastError() returned " + std::to_string( GetLastError() ) );
```

This throws an error, generating the following message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'PeekNamedPipeException'
  what():  GetLastError() returned 0
```

But if `PeekNamedPipe` fails, `GetLastError` should not return 0 (`== ERROR_SUCCESS`), right?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because more system functions are called (behind the scenes) between the `PeekNamedPipe` and your call to `GetLastError`.

Store the value from `GetLastError` in a temporary variable, and use that when constructing the string.

Comment: +1 In this particular case, the only thing that can conceivably be causing this is something invoked from the temporary construction of a `std::string` from the literal preamble of the exception message. `GetLastError()` *will* fire before the actual ctor, and obviously fire before the invoke of `to_string` or the actual throw, so that rules out pretty much everything else that I can see except that temp string construction.